# Fancybox and css

Tags: jquery, css, fancybox

I have a Fancybox that opens on pageload. Everything is working fine, exept I'm not able to style the pop-up box. It seem like it will not pick up my css.
By the way; I'm not familiar with js - I just copy from tutorials! So if the answer includes js, please be very spesific. Thank you!

In head:

```
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/js/jquery.fancybox/jquery.fancybox.css" media="screen" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/stylesheets/ups-screen.css" type="text/css" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/js/jquery.fancybox/jquery.fancybox-1.2.1.pack.js"></script>


<body onload="$(a'#popup').trigger('click');">
```

Right before closing body-tag:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#popup").fancybox().trigger('click');

});
```

The content to load:

```
<a id="popup" href="#melding"></a>
<div style="display: none;">
<div class="fancybox">
<div id="melding"><br />
<br />
<h3>Velkommen til min nye hjemmeside.</h3>
<br />
<p>Testing - Testing. </p>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

The css in the ups-screen stylesheet:

```
.fancybox {
width: 600px;
padding-left: 30px;
padding-right: 30px;
padding-bottom: 20px;
padding-top: 30px;
 }

#melding{ 
text-decoration:none;
}
#popup{
background-color:#444;
}
```

No matter what I try or do, it returns the same sized square without any padding.

Comment: are you seriously using fancybox v1.2.1? ... try upgrading at least to v1.3.4 [fancybox.net](http://fancybox.net) ... this old (1.2.1) version may have issues with the latest version of jQuery

Comment: Thank you for making me aware of this.  I actually downloaded 2.1.2, so I don't know wy I ended up with 1.2.1. I guess I was blind for a moment. Hopefully it will help to upgrade.

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#popup").fancybox({
        'padding' : 30,
        'width' : 600,
    }).trigger('click');
});
```

Here are some more examples: http://fancybox.net/blog

**Edit:**
The above solution is working if you have iframe loaded in fancybox.
In your case you need to set width and padding for #melding:

```css
#melding{ 
   text-decoration:none;
   width: 600px;
   padding: 30px 30px 20px 30px;

}
```

Comment: Sorry, no - it's still not changing size. But it kind of added the padding. Only not to the text, but the inner div that's included in the fancybox.css

Comment: I've also tried to påt the width and padding for #melding. Still not working. But I'll try to change the version of Fancybox. I actually downloaded 2.1.2, so I don't know wy I ended up with 1.2.1. I guess I was blind for a moment...

Answer (score 0):

```
...except I'm not able to style the pop-up box. 
It seem like it will not pick up my css.
```

Well, you got to know how fancybox works with `inline` content (the hidden `<div>` you want to display in fancybox) :

First, you are targeting the container with `id="melding"` with this html :

```
<a id="popup" href="#melding"></a>
```

When you open fancybox, the `<div id="melding">...</div>` is **MOVED** from its original position in the document into fancybox. A temporary *placeholder* is left instead so the content can be returned to where it was when you close fancybox.

... so this is how your (`inline`) content looks **before** opening fancybox:

```
<div style="display: none;">
 <div class="fancybox">
  <div id="melding"><br />
   <br />
   <h3>Velkommen til min nye hjemmeside.</h3>
   <br />
   <p>Testing - Testing. </p>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

.... and this is how it looks **after** you open fancybox (v2.1.2)

```
<div style="display: none;">
 <div class="fancybox">
  <div class="fancybox-placeholder" style="display: none; "></div>
 </div>
</div>
```

.... of course `<div id="melding">...</div>` is inside fancybox.

A question for you : Can you see the issue?
Answer : you are applying your style to the selector `.fancybox`

```
.fancybox {
  width: 600px;
  padding-left: 30px;
  padding-right: 30px;
  padding-bottom: 20px;
  padding-top: 30px;
}
```

... but that selector never made it to fancybox, so this why you cannot style it.

Your options :

**One** : set the style you want to `#melding` as properly pointed out by **@bbosternak**

...or

**Two** : change your html structure like

```
<div id="melding" style="display: none;">
 <div class="fancybox">
  <h3>Velkommen til min nye hjemmeside.</h3><br />
  <p>Testing - Testing. </p>
 </div>
</div>
```

Notice that I moved the `id="melding"` to the parent `<div>` of the `<div class="fancybox">`

Comment: Now I've updated to Fancybox 2.1.2 and done the changes you set up for me, and it works!!! Thank you so very much!